# Changing table structure causes React to lose track of the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I am trying to create a table component in React where both the columns and rows are dynamic and change over time. However, when the data changes, React throws an unexpected DOM mutation invariant violation.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/1797/. As you can see, the data changes after the initial render and React can no longer track the state of the DOM.

Code is here:

```
var Table = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function() {
      return {
        data: [
          {
            colA: { value: 'foo' },
          },
        ],
      };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr> {
                Object.keys(this.props.data[0]).map(function(key) {
                  return (<th>{ key }</th>);
                }.bind(this))
              } </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> {
              this.props.data.map(function(item) {
                return (<tr> { Object.keys(item).map(function(key) {
                  return (
                    <td>{ item[key] }</td>
                  );
                }.bind(this)) } </tr>);
              }.bind(this))    
            } </tbody>
          </table>
        );
    }
 });

var Main = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var data = [
        {
          colA: {
            value: 'foobar',
          },
        },
      ];
      this.setState({
        data: data,
      });
    }.bind(this), 3000);
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    var data = [
      {
        colA: {
          value: 'foo',
        },
        colB: {
          value: 'bar',
        }
      },
      {
        colA: {
          value: 'foo',
        },
        colB: {
          value: 'bar',
        }
      }
    ];

    return {
      data: data,
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<Table data={ this.state.data } />);
  },
});

React.render(<Main />, document.body);
console.log(React.renderToString(<Table/>));
```

I've tried all manner of adding key attributes to track various elements and nothing seems to solve this problem.

Rendering the table component with renderToString shows that React is inserting a bunch of  elements at various levels of the table. Is this the possible cause? See the DOM being rendered here:

```
<table data-reactid=".1" data-react-checksum="1098817301">
  <thead data-reactid=".1.0">
    <tr data-reactid=".1.0.0">
      <span data-reactid=".1.0.0.0"> </span>
      <th data-reactid=".1.0.0.1:0">colA</th>
      <span data-reactid=".1.0.0.2"> </span>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-reactid=".1.1">
    <span data-reactid=".1.1.0"> </span>
    <tr data-reactid=".1.1.1:0">
      <span data-reactid=".1.1.1:0.0"> </span>
      <td data-reactid=".1.1.1:0.1:0"><span data-reactid=".1.1.1:0.1:0.$value:0">foo</span></td>
      <span data-reactid=".1.1.1:0.2"> </span>
    </tr>
    <span data-reactid=".1.1.2"> </span>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see an error in that fiddle?

Comment: There's a setTimeout call that runs. You might have to wait a second.

Comment: ... no there isn't? http://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/ I think you got the wrong link.

Comment: You're right. My apologies. The correct link is http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/1797/

Comment: You could also just remove the space between `>` and `{`.  So `<tr>{ ` instead of `<tr> { `, and the same with the closing `>` and `}`.  The reason for this is mostly because `foo <b>bar</b>` shouldn't render as foo**bar**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the problem is with your indentation. If you start curly braces `{}` (curly braces to write javascript inside JSX) on a new line, your code works. Not sure why it happens though.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cwn2nebs/

```
var Table = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function() {
      return {
        data: [
          {
            colA: { value: 'foo' },
          },
        ],
      };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr> 
              {
                Object.keys(this.props.data[0]).map(function(key, idx) {
                  return (<th key={ idx } >{ key }</th>);
                }.bind(this))
              } 
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
            {
              this.props.data.map(function(item, idx) {
                return (
                <tr key={ idx }> 
                { 
                  Object.keys(item).map(function(key, i) {
                      return (
                        <td key={ i }>{ item[key] }</td>
                      );
                  }.bind(this)) } 
                </tr>);
              }.bind(this))

            } 
            </tbody>
          </table>
        );
    }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var data = [
        {
          colA: {
            value: 'foobar',
          }
        },
      ];
      this.setState({
        data: data,
      });
    }.bind(this), 3000);
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    var data = [
      {
        colA: {
          value: 'foo',
        },
        colB: {
          value: 'bar',
        }
      },
      {
        colA: {
          value: 'foo',
        },
        colB: {
          value: 'bar',
        }
      }
    ];

    return {
      data: data,
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<Table data={ this.state.data } />);
  },
});

React.render(<Main />, document.body);
```

**Update**

Using [JSX compiler](http://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html) I tried to convert part of your code to plain JS:

```
 render: function() {
        return (
          React.createElement("table", null, 
            React.createElement("thead", null, 
              React.createElement("tr", null, " ", 
                Object.keys(this.props.data[0]).map(function(key, idx) {
                  return (React.createElement("th", {key: idx }, key ));
                }.bind(this)), 
              " ")
            ), 
            React.createElement("tbody", null, " ", 
              this.props.data.map(function(item, idx) {
                return (React.createElement("tr", {key: idx }, " ",  Object.keys(item).map(function(key, i) {
                  return (
                    React.createElement("td", {key: i },  item[key] )
                  );
                }.bind(this)), " "));
              }.bind(this)), 

            " ")
          )
        );
    }
```

This is how `React.createElement` works:

```
React.createElement(type, props, children);
```

Notice the empty children for `tr` elements:

```
React.createElement("tr", null, " ", 
    Object.keys(this.props.data[0]).map(function(key, idx) {
        return (React.createElement("th", {key: idx }, key ));
    }.bind(this)), 
 " ")
```

But with curly brace on a new line, the compiled code looks like this (there is no empty (" ") children):

```
React.createElement("tr", null,     
    Object.keys(this.props.data[0]).map(function(key, idx) {
        return (React.createElement("th", {key: idx }, key ));
    }.bind(this))
)
```

I believe React converts `" "` children to `span` elements which is cause of the problem here, as you find out.

Comment: Good catch. What prompted you to try new lines?

Comment: Yeah, seriously good catch. Last thing I would have thought to try.

Comment: For the record, the placement of my brackets was causing React (or JSX?) to insert the spans, which Chrome would helpfully remove. Changing the placement no longer generates the spans on renderToString. At least I think that's right.